# Multiple JQuery different form selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms `one` and `two`, and based on which form is submitted I want to call a function based on that submitted value at the end of my logic.

I want to know if I can retrieve each selector as an array index, loop or a property or something to `var = tagsOrAnswerers`? And then maybe I can pass that argument onto my function which will be called.

```
<html>
     <form class="one">
         <input type="text" name="foo">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
     <form class="two">
         <input type="text"name="boo">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
</html>

<script>
       $('.one,.two').submit( function(){
       var fooOrBoo = $(this).find("input[name='foo'],[name='boo']").val();

       getBoo(ifBoo); //run this function if var fooOrBoo = 'boo';
       getFoo(ifFoo); //run this function if var fooOrBoo = 'foo';

});
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the form "name"? `if (this.className === "one") { getFoo(); } else { getBoo(); }`

Comment: Hey Andreas, trying to avoid using if/else for reasons what if I had morethan two forms.

Comment: `var formDependendFunctions = { "one": getFoo, "two": getBoo }; if (formDependendFunctions[this.className]) { formDependendFunctions[this.className](this); }`

Comment: I suggest, if you want to call different code logics on each form submit, then register different submit events. Writing if blocks with one submit event is not really a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a common name for the answers for each form. I named it as "answer"

```
   <div class="forms">
             <form class="one">
                 <input type="text" name="answer">
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
             </form>
             <form class="two">
                 <input type="text"name="answer">
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
             </form>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script>
$('.forms > form').submit( function(){
   var data = $( this ).serializeArray();
   console.log(data); // gives the current data of the forms

  //using the data you can call whatever function you want using a switch statment
});
</script>
```

Comment: I liked the fact that `.serializeArray()`was able to actually bring back data. Thanks @madi.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a single event approach try this but it really depend on what your functions ve to do

```js
 $('.forms > form').submit( function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var formN = $('form').index(this);
   switch(formN){
     case 0:
         alert("FUNCTION1");
       break;
     case 1:
         alert("FUNCTION2");
       break;
     //and so on.....
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="forms">
     <form class="one">
         <input type="text" name="foo">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
     <form class="two">
         <input type="text"name="boo">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
</div>
```