# Jquery validate two forms - Syntax to recognize form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Always with the same dilemn not resolved (two step forms on the same page with no working jquery validate. **The two forms and all fields have different names and id.)**
(Beginner jquery and ajax).

```
 $('form[name="clt"]').validate({
});
```

First of all is it the right syntax to recognize form ?
It's two step forms (validation step by step/form). The errors messages aren't working
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple JQuery different form selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995625/multiple-jquery-different-form-selectors)

Comment: Precision : two step form with step validation.... (step by step)

Comment: Syntax for the form is correct. name is optional, useful if there are multiple forms. double quotes is also not required, unless there is whitespace.

Comment: Thanks , I'm searching what is wrong cause it's not working. Seem to mix first form with second one.

Comment: what about showing us some code? the two forms and the javascript you use to validate? This line of code has a right syntax but can be wrong for your code

Comment: of course.
//First of all  ---> no accepted field
if(!empty($errors2)) {

  echo display_errors2($errors2);
//Second way to retrieve data by array cause I need a message with them on step 2 form 
} else {

   $data2 = array(); 
   $data2['client_id'] = $client_id;
   $data2['client_civilite'] = $client_civilite;
   $data2['client_name'] = $client_name;
   $data2['res2'] = "passed";


   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($data2);
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .validate() for each form. Did you named them differently?

In your example you have only:

```
$('form[name="clt"]').validate({
});
```

You have to have two:

```
$('form[name="form1"]').validate({});
$('form[name="form2"]').validate({});
```

If it's not two forms as it's in your title but two step form as in your description:

```
$(".buttonYouClickForNextStep").click(function () {
     $('form[name="clt"]').validate({
    });
}
```

Comment: I use different ID for each one.

Comment: I used two.
The form 1 is working well.   I thought the problem come from the fact I don't want to retrieve data in the same way. iF errors ---> messages errors by data, if not array data cause I need to retrieve two of them for a distinct message.